# htaccess redirect issue - [NC,L] flag doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When I click on page-details, the next page had the previous page appended to itself.

This is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^item-([0-9]+)/(.*)/details/?$ page-details.php?id_item=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^item-([0-9]+)/(.*)/details/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^item-([0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ page.php?id_item=$1 [NC,L]
```

Hint?

Comment: If it is Apache 2.4 or later, try `END` flag.

Comment: I did it and didn't work.

Comment: Why should the fact that "a page is appended to another" have anything to do with rewriting?

Comment: The page works correctly with this: #RewriteRule ^ristorante-([0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ restaurant.php?id_restaurant=$1 [NC,L,QSA]